# Operation always gives me 0 as result

Tags: c

```
b=((a/n)*100);
```

This line of code always gives me 0 regardless of the value of "a" and "n".
I don't think this depends on anything else in the code, since everything else is working fine.
This is probably very stupid, but can anyone help?

Comment: my crystal ball says you're doing integer division and `n > a`

Comment: You haven't shown us enough to know what the problem might be.  How are the variables declared?  How are they assigned values?  How do you print the result?

Comment: @Cu be It is unable always to produce 0. For example consider a equal to 1 and n equal to 1.:)

Comment: If `a` and `n` are both 1, that gives me 100. What values did you actually test this with?

Comment: " don't think this depends on anything else in the code" Yes it does, namely the variable declarations of all variables involved. Without it, nobody can answer the question, just speculate.

Comment: Thanks, yano is right, I'm doing an integer division with n>a

Comment: @Cube to elaborate, in integer division, the fractional part is discarded and only the whole number quotient is retained. So even 999/1000 is 0 with integer division.

Comment: `double b=(  ( ((double)a)/n)*100);` is probably what you need.